# Call by name, lambda calculs. Multiplication

Tags: lambda-calculus

How to multiply in CBN strategy?

```
mul = \m.\n.\f. m(n f)
two = \f.\x. f (f x)

mul two two = (\m.\n.\f. m(n f)) (\f.\x. f (f x)) (\f.\x. f (f x)) =
= \f. (\f0.\x0. f0 (f0 x0)) ((\f1.\x1. f1 (f1 x1)) f)
```

As I understand, after that, calculations in the CBN strategy stop, because in CBN no reduce under abstractions.

is it possible to get 4 in my example after multiplying in the CBN strategy?

Comment: Today is the day after I answered your question and did not see any feedback. So in rereading your question it dawned on me that you might want the literal answer of `4` and not the [Church encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Church_encoding) of `4`. If so then please say so.  The reason my answer using the noted tool does not result is `4` is that the tool does not know to apply a `delta-reduction` if a rule is added for `4`, I.e. `four = λf.λx.f (f (f fx))`.

Comment: My question was about building mul-operation for call-by-name strategy. CBN doen't reduce inside abstraction but you was reduced indised abstraction in your solution

Comment: Call-by-name
`As normal order, but no reductions are performed inside abstractions. For example λx.(λx.x)x is in normal form according to this strategy, although it contains the redex (λx.x)x.

    A normal form is an equivalent expression that cannot be reduced any further under the rules imposed by the form`

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26522960/applicative-order-call-by-value-and-normal-order-call-by-name-differences

Comment: Your previous comment should be included in the question. Lack of that is why I was unsure of my given answer. As such and by the lack of an up-vote do you consider my answer of no use to you? If so then I will just delete it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't consider this a full answer because the tool I used to demonstrate the result may not work the same as you seek. Although if it is not what you seek then please clarify.

Using [Lambda Calculus Calculator](https://lambdacalc.io/)

In the left column add your two definitions separately (copy and paste works). It will convert `\f` to `λf` upon entry.

[image]

Below that select the `Active Strategy`.

I will take it that the `call by name` strategy and the option `Outermost First` work the same.

[image]

In the upper right enter your expression

[image]

Click `Start`

The first reduction will be displayed and show the button

[image]

click the button.

The normal form at the end is

[image]

Looks like `4` in Lambda Calculus to me.

Again, you will have to decide if that answers your question.

---

Notice that on the right not all of the reductions are beta-reductions, some are [delta-reductions](http://barrywatson.se/lsi/lsi_delta_reduction.html).

[image]

As those are just helping to simplify the display I think of those as just syntactic sugar substitutions, they do not change the final outcome. In other words they translate to/from the rewrite rules, E.g instead of seeing `two` in the derivation it would show `λf.λx.f (f x)`.

If at the start you use `(\m.\n.\f. m(n f)) (\f.\x. f (f x)) (\f.\x. f (f x))` instead of `mul two two` and click `Start` you will get the same result without the delta-reductions.

---

Your last variation `\f. (\f0.\x0. f0 (f0 x)) ((\f1.\x1. f1 (f1 x1)) f)`  results in `λf.λx0.f(f(f(fx)))` which is not the same as the others. I don't know where you picked up the `0`s in that expression but it is the source of why the output is different.